# Unable to use search API of Facebook in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use Search API of Facebook in PHP. I have used the Facebook Sdk latest version, but it is throwing the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook\Facebook::api()

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
    require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => '{app_id}',
      'app_secret' => '{app_secret}',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
    ]);

    $access_token =  $fb->getApp()->getAccessToken();   //NOTE: i had to use getAPP() because it was also throwing error here for undefined function

    $query = urlencode('jack');
    $type = 'user';
    $ret = $fb->api('/search?q='.$query.'&type='.$type);
    echo json_encode($ret);
```

Basically I have to find the users by name "jack"

But if I try the same on Facebook Explorer then it works fine. Here is what I tried there:

```
search?q=jack&type=user
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: _“please let me know what i am doing wrong here”_ - you are trying to use the PHP SDK v5 with code that was written for an older version - in v5, the `Facebook` class does not have an `api` method any more. Use `get` instead, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/Facebook#get

Comment: @CBroe i tried to use get, it gives "access token' error that time

Comment: and when i tried to set access token as $fb->setAccessToken($access_token); then it throw the error of undefined function setAccessToken

Comment: Same thing again - you are using outdated methods ... The documentation has lots of examples how to use the v5 SDK to make basic API requests, f.e. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile

Comment: all the examples are using "'/me'" but i have to perform "search" here, should i pass acess token for "search" also?
i tried to pass it, as $fb->get('/search?q='.$query.'&type='.$type, '{access-token}');
now it threw a different error. i.e.  An active access token must be used to query information

Comment: You removed the {...} around the access token, right? (That is only used in the documentation to indicate that this is a placeholder.)

Comment: yes i did. i passed the actual token there, it was just for comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155412/discussion-between-amrinder-singh-and-cbroe).

Comment: CBroe can you please provide me some example. that would be really appreciated

Comment: And what _type_ of access token did you use?